# BroadcastReceiver Won't work in android 9 after avoid the linter reports UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, jobintentservice

Im using scheduledAlarm to trigger `BroadcastReceiver` which Start `JobIntentService` it worked fine but when i inspected the code i got `UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver` I added if condition check in `onReceive` method to fillter the action  but `JobIntentService` didn't work. but if I replaced the condition it worked fine. Note that I'm using android 9.any help thanks in advance
**BroadCastReceiver**

```
class BootBroadCastReciever : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

 if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
         val i = Intent(context, IncomingRequestServices::class.java)
            //Start the service
            context?.let {
                IncomingRequestServices.enqueueWork(it,i)
        }
    }

    }

    companion object {
        const val REQUEST_CODE = 12345
    }
}
```

**Mainfest file**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   <receiver android:name=".BoardcastReciever.BootBroadCastReciever" android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
          android:name=".Services.IncomingRequestServices"
          android:exported="false"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
```

**JobIntentService**

```
class IncomingRequestServices  : JobIntentService() {

    var CHANNEL_ID = "ChannelID"


    override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
        //I check for news from server and send notification to user
    }




    companion object
    {
        const val JOB_ID = 101
        const val NOTIF_ID = 82
        fun enqueueWork(context: Context, work: Intent)
        {
            JobIntentService.enqueueWork(context,IncomingRequestServices::class.java, JOB_ID, work)
        }
    }
```

**alarm**

```
  private fun scheduleAlarm() {
        // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, BootBroadCastReciever::class.java)
        // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
        alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, BootBroadCastReciever.REQUEST_CODE,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        // Setup periodic alarm every 5 seconds
        val firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() // first run of alarm is immediate
        val intervalMillis = 60000 // as of API 19, alarm manager will be forced up to 60000 to save battery
        val alarm = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        // See https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, intervalMi

llis.toLong(), alarmPendingIntent)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add the check to your `onReceive()`, the broadcast `Intent` that was triggered by the `AlarmManager` got ignored. This is because you check for the ACTION in the `Intent` and you didn't set the ACTION in the `Intent` you send via `AlarmManager`.

To fix this, just add the ACTION:

```
val intent = Intent(applicationContext, BootBroadCastReciever::class.java)
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)
// Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, BootBroadCastReciever.REQUEST_CODE,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

Comment: I added the action but didn't work still the same problem@David Wasser

Comment: Add debug logging or set breakpoints. Does `onReceive()` get called when the alarm triggers?

Comment: `onReceive()` not called  @David Wasser